# RxJS interval function seems inacurate for time measurement

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

For learning purposes I am trying to build a stopwatch using RxJS `interval()` function in Angular but here is what I get :

[image: Result]

using

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stopwatch',
  templateUrl: './stopwatch.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stopwatch.component.css']
})
export class StopwatchComponent implements OnInit {
  msCounter = interval(1);
  ms = 0;
  ms1 = 0;

  secCounter = interval(1000);
  sec = 0;

  centCounter = interval(100);
  cent = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.secCounter.subscribe(value => this.sec = value);
    this.msCounter.subscribe(value => this.ms = Math.floor(value / 1000));
    this.msCounter.subscribe(value => this.ms1 = value );
    this.centCounter.subscribe(value => this.cent = value );
  }


}
```

As you can see seconds don't match milliseconds which don't match centiseconds either..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interval timer cannot be accurate down to milliseconds in this way.

Each emission of the interval will be on a new JS "frame", so Angular must complete a full cycle of change detection and so forth (as you are changing a property which your view is bound to) before the next possible opportunity for the interval to fire. That will take far more than 1ms to complete in almost all circumstances.

It is worth understanding that there is only ever a single "thread" in the Javascript runtime for a given web page, so if one thing is happening (say, change detection), another thing (say, emitting on the interval() observable) *cannot* happen at the "same time", it has to wait for the current execution frame to complete.

Comment: I see do you know a way to accurately do the same thing ?

Comment: How accurately? You could set the interval to, say, 500ms or 1000ms then keep track of the actual time you started and do something like `(new Date())-(startTime)` to get the difference in actual time from the start to the current time?